# the validation client-side for bach field form yii

Tags: php, validation, yii

I want to validate and insert multiple records from single form.
I've used something like this in my form. but the validation client-side don't work. how can validate fields in view file?

```
<?php
 $items[]=new IpUser;
 $items[]=new IpUser;
 $items[]=new IpUser;
 $items[]=new IpUser;
?>
<div class="form">
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>
<table>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Price</th><th>Count</th><th>Description</th></tr>
<?php foreach($items as $i=>$item): ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]domain"); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::error($item,'[$i]domain'); ?>

</td>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]url"); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::error($item,'[$i]url'); ?>

</td>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextField($item,"[$i]ipv4"); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::error($item,'[$i]ipv4'); ?>

</td>
<td><?php echo CHtml::activeTextArea($item,"[$i]numberIpv4"); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::error($item,'[$i]numberIpv4'); ?>

</td>
</tr>
<?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

use cactiveform widget

```
$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'enableClientValidation'=>true,
'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
)
);
```

Comment: i must create  multiple records in one form submission realy.

Comment: use yii multicreate with client validation

Comment: refer this  for validation https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/9811 .hope this will help you

Comment: tank you i try it and will say you